# onload not working after $.mobile.changePage with data and between two .php pages

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have 2 php pages and I am calling the second one like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage("cuestionario.php?", { transition: "slide", type: "post", data: data ,changeHash:true,reloadPage:true},true, true);
```

but, in the second page I have many functions with alerts just 4 trying, but they are not working after the page has been charged, but when I push the F5 button everything works just fine.

Comment: I`m trying to find that out past hour...

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/

Are you actually using the onload event? You should be using pageshow if you are using jQuery Mobile.